# Verifying if two numbers are equal using ArrayLists

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, programming-challenge, array

I have some question about the code below. It works correctly, but:

- Is there a better/another way to solve the exercise (as an expert would have done:) or mine it's perfectly done?
- Also, I don't see the point of using ArrayList instead of a normal vector like `int a[]`.
- In the method `analysis` I wanted to set as parameters `(ArrayList a,ArrayList b)` but an error (incompatible types List cannot be converted to `ArrayList`) appears in this `int a = Testing.analysis(seq1, seq2, t1);` line. I thought  I was working with `ArrayList` since I instantiated my sequences as such.

**Exercise:**

> Perform a program that uses a function that returns a 1 if two very large numbers (digits greater than 5 and where each digit is an element of the arrayList) are equal and a 0 otherwise.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Entry
>
> Number 1: 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> Number 2: 1 4 6 8 9 0
>
> Output "They are not equal numbers"

---

```
class Testing {

static int analysis(List a, List b, int t) throws Exception { //using 
//ArrayList instead of List marks an error, why?

    int c = 0;

    if (a.size() == b.size() && a.size() > 5) {

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            if (a.get(i) == b.get(i)) {
                c++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("oops! the lengths are not the same or some 
    of the sequence is less than 6");
        throw new Exception(); //to finish the method
    }

    if (c == t) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
}

public class Tarea24agoENGLISH {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

    List seq1 = new ArrayList(); //I wanted to write this List <int> seq=new ArrayList<int>(); but it marked an error, why?
    System.out.println("Introduce the length of the sequence1 ");
    int t1 = q.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < t1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce the digits for sequence1");
        int n = q.nextInt();
        seq1.add(n);
    }

    List seq2 = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("Introduce the length of the sequence2");
    int t2 = q.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < t2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introdce the digits for sequence2");
        int n = q.nextInt();
        seq2.add(n);
    }

    int a = Testing.analysis(seq1, seq2, t1);
    if (a == 1) {
        System.out.println("same numbers");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\n different numbers");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Note: `int[]` is not a vector, it is an array. There is no such thing as a vector in Java, except for an old, outdated class called `java.util.Vector` that should never be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Declaring a method

> ```
> static int analysis(List a, List b, int t) throws Exception { //using
> ```

This could be just

```
    public static int isEqual(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
```

This should not be an `ArrayList`, as that is an implementation.  You want to use the interface here because that accepts more things without adding limitations.

You have to say `<Integer>` rather than `<int>` because generics have to be objects, not primitives.

If you have more questions about why variants of your code are getting errors, first try searching on Stack Overflow.  If you can't find anything, then post a MCVE on Stack Overflow.  As was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31754638/6660678).

In general, you want to give methods verb names, like `analyze` or `isEqual`.  I find `isEqual` more descriptive.

You don't need to throw a checked `Exception`.  You could throw an unchecked exception like `RunTimeException` or `IllegalArgumentException`.  If you throw an unchecked exception, you don't need the `throws` declaration.

You don't need `t` as it is just `a.size()`.  So just use `a.size()`.

#### Handling exceptional cases

> ```
>     if (a.size() == b.size() && a.size() > 5) {
> ```

Consider flipping the logic around.

```
    if (a.size() < 6) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The numbers have to have at least 6 digits.");
    }
```

Now code and message match.  We don't have to figure out that `> 5` means 6 or more.  And then negate that for the `else`.  We don't need an `else` because `throw` ends the execution of the method.  Implicitly, the rest of the method is in an `else`.

```
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        return 0;
    }
```

You could throw an exception here, but as [previously mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174075/71574), this feels more like a false condition.  So you can return your false value.

#### Early return

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
>         if (a.get(i) == b.get(i)) {
>             c++;
>         }
>     }
> ```

This could be

```
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) != b.get(i)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

If you find an unequal value, you can return immediately.

> ```
>     if (c == t) {
>         return 1;
>     } else {
>         return 0;
>     }
> ```

And this could be just

```
    return 1;
```

By returning early, you actually simplify the code.

#### Input to a list

> ```
>     System.out.println("Introduce the length of the sequence1 ");
>     int t1 = q.nextInt();
> ```

This is a weird way to do it.  If you do it this way, you can just use an array rather than a `List`.  Normally when you use a `List`, you would get digits until something happened.  For example, something like:

```
    System.out.println("Introduce the digits for sequence1");
    for (char digit : q.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
        seq1.add(digit - '0');
    }
```

Subtracting `'0'` from `digit` converts `digit` from a character to a number.  You could also do `Character.digit(digit, 10)` which is arguably more portable and flexible.

You may have to cast to `Integer` if there is a warning.

Anyway, this allows you to enter the digits all next to each other and terminate the number by hitting return.

Comment: why did you exclude the '0' character ?, in the last for loop

Comment: why is this`for (int digit : q.nextInt()) {
        seq1.add(digit);}` wrong? (I was trying to change your code to make it more descriptive)

Comment: That's more of a Stack Overflow question than a Code Review question.  Hints:  how many digits are in the number that `q.nextInt()` returns?  What does `q.nextInt()` return?  The `for` loop is expecting something that implements `Iterable<Integer>` there.

Comment: Answer: `q.nextInt()` returns only 1 digit. So there's no way to change `char` by `int`?

Comment: oh and I should let you know that for some reason SO block me :( so I can't post questions there anymore

Answer (score 2):

First thing I noticed don't count how many digits are equal, soon as 1 digit is unequal return false, if the loop finishes return true.  Also it seems to me if the sizes are unequal the proper response would be false not an error.

Comment: the code doesn't need to count how many digits are equal. If the loop finishes and return true then it's because the numbers are equal

Comment: yes exactly as my answer states

Comment: if the sizes are unequal the response is "different numbers", not an error. I checked with a sequences of lenght 6 and 7

Comment: But the exercise doesn't mention unequal lengths, it would be reasonable to assume that they would elicit the same response as any other set of numbers.

Comment: however it's not supposed to do that, it should throw an error

Comment: Ok, that's not mentioned in the exercise.

Comment: doesn't look like more sophisticated with the 'throw error'? I know the exercise doesn't ask for it but it doesn't  specify what to do in such cases, where the lengths aren't the same

Comment: Since equal lengths isn't a requirement of the input your getting, returning an error is misleading and frustrating to the user.

Comment: :D haha ok, I'll change it..